# MySQL select join many to many tables plus IN and NOT IN

Tags: mysql, join, exists

I have 3 tables: Products, Tags, and products_tags(many to many between Products and Tags).
in my schema, a product can have zero to many tags and a tag can have zero to many products.
Now i want to select products that have certain tags and don't have certain tags.

Products table:

> idproducts  /  name
>
> 1 / samsung galaxy
>
> 2 / samsung note1
>
> 3 / samsung note2
>
> 4 / iphone 4gs

Tags table:

> idtags / word
>
> 1 / samsung
>
> 2 / galaxy
>
> 3 / note1
>
> 4 / note2
>
> 5 / iphone
>
> 6 / 4gs
>
> 7 / apple

Products_Tags Table:

> product / tag
>
> 1 / 1
>
> 1 / 2
>
> 2 / 1
>
> 2 / 3
>
> 3 / 1
>
> 3 / 4
>
> 4 / 5
>
> 4 / 6

I have the query below, but it gives me the products with tags i **didn't** want cause they have some other tags and as result of join they appear in the result set.

> SELECT * FR0M products AS p
>
> ```
> JOIN products_tags AS pt ON pt.product = p.idproducts
>
> JOIN tags AS t ON t.idtags = pt.tag
>
> WHERE t.word IN ('samsung', 'mobile')
>
> AND t.word NOT IN ('note1', 'note2')
> ```

If i wanted Samsung Galaxy and i defined to have tags like 'samsung' and not have 'note1' and 'note2'. What would be the query for this?

P.S. I thought maybe EXISTS or NOT EXISTS should be used, but i am just not able to figure out how i should use them.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not working because the join selects all elements with tag samsung, including `samsung note 1` and `samsung note 2`. You can use `group_concat` to group all the tag names and then filter on them with `like` or `Regexp` as follows:

```
select *, GROUP_CONCAT(t.word) tagname from products as p
  inner JOIN products_tags AS pt ON pt.products = p.productid
  inner Join tags t on t.idtags = pt.tags 
group by p.productid
having tagname not REGEXP 'note1|note2' 
   and tagname REGEXP 'samsung|mobile'
```

some important resources:

- [Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- [Regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

Comment: tnx Kasi, it works now, but do i have other options rather than regexp? I am not familiar with it and prefer to use other options if i could

Comment: `Regexp` will allow you to group several of the expressions together, but you can also use `Like` for this purpose e.g `tagname not like '%note1%' and tagname not like '%note2%'`

Answer (score 0):

You want all products with a tag of samsung or mobile, but without a note 1 or note2 tag?

```
SELECT * FR0M products AS p

JOIN products_tags AS pt ON pt.product = p.idproducts

JOIN tags AS tp ON tp.idtags = pt.tag and (tp.word = 'samsung' or tp.word = 'mobile')

JOIN tags AS tn ON tn.idtags = pt.tag and tn.word <> 'note1' and tn.word <> 'note2'
```

Would be one way.

your attempt doesn't work because any row that satisfies the in clause can't possibly satify the not in one. Neither samsung nor mobile are note1 or note2

The above does one join to get samsung or mobile and then joins to the tags table again (with a different alias) to get all those without a note1, or note2 tag.

Comment: tnx Tony, but it still gives me the products i don't want 'samsung note1' and 'samsung note2'

Comment: using your query, i get the whole 3 products that have 'samsung' tag. I need to exclude products that have the tags i don't want even though if the same product has some of the tags i wanted.
e.g even though products 'samsung note1' and 'samsung note2' have the tag 'samsung', but they have tags 'note1' and 'note2' and i want them to be out of the result set. I just want the product 'samsung galaxy' that does have tag 'samsung' and doesn't have tags 'note1' and 'note2'

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, hmmm going to have to think about this one